# Upload file to google cloud storage by javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload files to my own buckets by `PUT` method but couldn't get it to work:

```
function upload(url, data) {
    var pd = new XMLHttpRequest();
    pd['open']('PUT', "http://storage.googleapis.com/" + url, true);
    pd['setRequestHeader']('Content-type', 'text/html');
    pd['setRequestHeader']('x-goog-acl', 'public-read');
    pd['setRequestHeader']('Authorization', 'Bearer *********F0aIu4NbTd6A');
    pd['setRequestHeader']('Content-length', data['length']);
    pd['setRequestHeader']('Connection', 'close');
    pd['send'](data);
}
upload('bucked/index.html','<b>hello</b>');
```

Comment: Can you include the error details? Also, your requested bucket is "bucked" - is that a typo? It might be worth checking to see if that bucket already exists using the command 'gsutil ls gs://bucked'.

Comment: you should try S3. GS is just the copy ( though not a good one).

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to indicate that [CORS](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) is not set up for your bucket.

Comment: for able to set CORS setting, i need to use PUT method so for able to use PUT request i need  to use  PUT request that i cant use :)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem:

```
request.setRequestHeader('x-goog-acl', 'public-read');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
request.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
request.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);.
```

1. set proper origin
2. add response header (same as in your request) ["authorization", "content-type", "x-file-name", "x-file-size", "x-goog-acl"]
3. PUT and OPTIONS methods
   I found solution on this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Troubleshooting%20CORS-Related-Problems)

sample cors.json

```
[
    {
        "origin": ["*", "http://localhost:8080", "https://localhost:8080"],
        "responseHeader": ["authorization", "content-type", "x-file-name", "x-file-size", "x-goog-acl"],
        "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS"],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

To set this configuration use gsutil cors set cors.json gs://your_bucket

PS.
Connection and Content-lenght are not necessary, JS would throw some errors to Console.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you could tell us how the PUT operation is failing.  Have you tried uploading to commondatastorage.googleapis.com rather than storage.googleapis.com?

Comment: their server doesn't response as needed to first OPTIONS request

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/**. Origin http://www.**.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: storage.googleapis.com is equivalent to commondatastorage.googleapis.com so that shouldn't the cause of the problem but we need more info about how the put request is failing.